# Beamer Singapore delete name of sections in navigation bar

Tags: beamer, formatting, lyx

I use the Singapore theme from Beamer with several modifications. I want to edit the preamble, so that the section names don't appear in the navigation bar and the space for the progress indicator (circles) is gained. My mother tongue is Spanish and I've had to use google translate, so forgive any lack of linguistic coherence.

[image]

Preamble (LyX)

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usetheme{Singapore}

\makeatletter


\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1ex,leftskip=2ex,rightskip=2ex,sep=0pt]{section in head/foot}%
    \hfill%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
    \insertsection%
    \hfill%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
    \usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=structure.fg!40!white}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!90!white}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=structure.fg!40!white}

   
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\useinnertheme{rounded}


\newif\ifnavbeforecurrent


\pretocmd\insertnavigation{\navbeforecurrenttrue}{}{}


\defbeamertemplate*{mini frame in current subsection}{changing}[1][50]
{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{0.1cm}{0.1cm}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0.05cm}{0.05cm}}{0.05cm}
    \ifnavbeforecurrent
        \pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
    \else
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \fi
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}[changing]


\defbeamertemplate*{mini frame}{changing}
{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{0.1cm}{0.1cm}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0.05cm}{0.05cm}}{0.05cm}
    \pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
  \global\navbeforecurrentfalse
}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame}[changing]


\setbeamercovered{invisible}
% or whatever (possibly just delete it)

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%\usecolortheme{seahorse}
%\usecolortheme{rose}


\usepackage{ae,aecompl}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{gris}{gray}{0.85}


\usepackage{cancel}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{gris}{gray}{0.85}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\useinnertheme[rounded=false]{tcolorbox}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=structure, fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=structure!40!, fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[square]
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{%
  \setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=black}%
}{}

\setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=orange!90!, fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{bg=orange!40!, fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[square]
\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{%
  \setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=black}%
}{}

\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{bg=cyan!100!, fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{bg=cyan!40!, fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[square]
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{%
  \setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=black}%
}{}


\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Why can‘t you demonstrate your problem and your attempt to solve it with less code? Did you read the beamer manual? Where did you get this code from? Thank you

Comment: Please minimize your code removing everything, that is not needed, e.g., all commented `\usetheme` commands. And also extend your code to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), that can be used to reproduce the problem. [This could be done using LyX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4488/277964), but I would recommend to do it using a LaTeX editor and posting the LaTeX code, because here are much more LaTeX helpers than LyX helpers.

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{}` to remove the section name from the headline:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Singapore}

%Para el pie de página estructurado
\makeatletter
   
% para los colores de los círculos del encabezado:
\useoutertheme{miniframes}

% Un indicador que nos dice cómo deben elaborarse los círculos
\newif\ifnavbeforecurrent

% Restablecer la bandera antes de cada barra de navegación
\pretocmd\insertnavigation{\navbeforecurrenttrue}{}{}

% Cambiar el código de dibujo del círculo para que cambie base en la señal
\defbeamertemplate*{mini frame in current subsection}{changing}[1][50]
{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{0.1cm}{0.1cm}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0.05cm}{0.05cm}}{0.05cm}
    \ifnavbeforecurrent
        \pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
    \else
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \fi
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}[changing]

% Después de dibujar el círculo para el marco actual, cambiar la señal
\defbeamertemplate*{mini frame}{changing}
{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{0.1cm}{0.1cm}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0.05cm}{0.05cm}}{0.05cm}
    \pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
  \global\navbeforecurrentfalse
}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame}[changing]

\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{}


\begin{document}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the collaboration, exactly what I wanted. I even think I have some of his code in the footer editing.

Comment: @JF018 You're welcome!